# A recursive check for a winner in TicTacToe using a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am making a TicTacToe game in Java I am required to use a two-dimensional array and to use recursion to check if there is a winner.

I feel like I could easily do a non-recursive check for a winner, but I don't know where to start if I were to use recursion to do it because I am very new at recursion.  Could someone guide me on where to start the process of such an algorithm?

Comment: It is an extra credit assignment. It is eating at me and I can't find any ideas online.

Comment: What exactly does your teacher mean by recursive check? What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of iterating through the board places and seeing if they are equal, he wants me to use recursion to see if they are equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your board looks something like:

```
            |            |
 cell[0][0] | cell[1][0] | cell[2][0]
            |            |
------------+------------+------------
            |            |
 cell[0][1] | cell[1][1] | cell[2][1]
            |            |
------------+------------+------------
            |            |
 cell[0][2] | cell[1][2] | cell[2][2]
            |            |
```

One way is to simply check adjacent cells recursively (in a single direction). For example (pseudo-code):

```
def checkSame (val, cellX, cellY. deltaX, deltaY):
    # No winner if check value is empty.

    if val == empty: return false

    # Winner if we've gone off edge. No need to worry about < 0
    # since one direction is always ascending but I've left it
    # in anyway.

    if cellX > 2 or cellY > 2: return true
    if cellX < 0 or cellY < 0: return true

    # No winner if piece has changed.

    if cell[cellX][cellY] != val: return false

    # Otherwise use recursion to check next one.

    return checkSame (val, cellX + deltaX, cellY + deltaY, deltaX, deltaY)
```

Then, we just have to check the eight possible start-point/direction values:

```
# Check rows.

if checkSame (cell[0][0], 0, 0, 1, 0): return true
if checkSame (cell[0][1], 0, 1, 1, 0): return true
if checkSame (cell[0][2], 0, 2, 1, 0): return true

# Check columns.

if checkSame (cell[0][0], 0, 0, 0, 1): return true
if checkSame (cell[1][0], 1, 0, 0, 1): return true
if checkSame (cell[2][0], 2, 0, 0, 1): return true

# Check diagonals.

if checkSame (cell[0][0], 0, 0, 1, 1): return true
return checkSame (cell[0][2], 0, 2, 1, -1)
```

Now, granted that's a fairly limited (and contrived) use of recursion but, as you say, it's not really a situation suited to recursion anyway. Far better is just to use eight `if` statements, provided you're not planning of expanding this to more than standard 3x3 tic-tac-toe.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works wonders, and now my recursive thinking has expanded (I was only familiar with backtracking).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using recursion for this seems a little forced. Nevertheless, one idea is based on the definition of a win: three of X or O in a row in any direction. Start by picking a potential starting point (any place but the middle, which can't start a 3-square row) and pick a direction that might work. (The set of directions that might work is a function of the starting square.) The recursive step is: if you need *n* in a row of, say, X, in a particular direction, and the current position has an X, then take a step in that direction and look for (*n* - 1) in a row in that direction starting from there. Stop when *n* = 0. Do this entire process for every starting point and direction until you find a win or run out of choices.

That's enough of a clue, I think, to get you started.